# Is it possible to randomize a single word within a String attribute within an object from an array of possible options?

Tags: java

I'm very new to java and coding in general, so I apologize if this is a simple thing. I want to know if it's possible to add a variable within a string that will be randomized when the item itself is chosen from the ArrayList of options.

I've already created the objects, put them in an ArrayList, and have a method that randomly calls indices from the ArrayList and prints their attributes. However, some (not all) I would like to randomize a part of the "name" attribute from another separate Array. Is there a way to do this? If possible, I'd like it to be randomized each time its called, so in the case that I call that particular object twice from the ArrayList, its "name" attribute would not be identical (unless by chance the same suffix is called from the random name Array twice).

```
//Doesn't need randomization
Item r1 = new Item("Static Name", 1000);

// (X) needs to be either "Title", "Callsign", or "Identifier"
Item r2 = new Item("Random (X)", 500);
```

UPDATE:

I followed DevilsHnd's suggestion, but it doesn't seem to replace anything.

```
//declared in class
String[] suffix = {"Title","Callsign","Nickname"};

//as part of toString()

if (name.contains("(X)")) {
        name.replace("(X)", [new Random().nextInt(((suffix.length - 1) - 0) + 1) + 0]);
```

My toString still prints out "Random (X)" instead of a desired "Random Title".
I am able to get it to work if I remove the `if` function and use a static value for the replacement, like `name = name.replace("(X)","Title");`, but I still can't figure out how to get it to replace it with a value from the suffix array.

Comment: You probably want to clarify exactly when the `Item`'s value becomes static.  This sounds like it would probably be when `toString()` is called the first time.  (So ... `toString() { if  (null == value) { value = generateValueFromTemplate(); } return value; }`.  I'm assuming you want the value to become constant the first time it is "accessed".  There's ways to do it by overriding the methods in `ArrayList`, but it's going to be more complicated that way

Comment: why not just divide the string attribute further into separate attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get what you mean but you may get an idea from the following:

```
String[] attributes = {"Title", "Callsign", "Identifier"};
String itemString = "Random (X)";
if (itemString.contains("(X)")) {
    itemString = itemString.replace(
                "(X)", 
                attributes[new Random().nextInt(((attributes.length - 1) - 0) + 1) + 0]
            );
}
System.out.println(itemString);
Item r2 = new Item(itemString, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This got me much closer than I was before. I was able to basically just use the .replace method without an if statement to get what I needed, but I'm only able to get it to work if the replacement is a static String, like "Title". I'm still not able to pull the replacement from an Array of options. EDIT: Nevermind!  This worked perfectly!  I just had some syntax issues.

Comment: @PhantomLotus - You can certainly do that. It was only shown above so as to display clarity in the reasoning. Something like: `String itemString = "Random (X)".replace("(X)", attributes[new Random().nextInt(((attributes.length - 1) - 0) + 1) + 0]);` will do just fine. If "(X)" is in the supplied string then "(X)" will be **replaced** by a random element from the **attributes[]** Array, otherwise the **replace()** method simply does nothing to the supplied String. Keep in mind though that if a String had 2 "(X)" tags (or more) then each would contain the same attribute.